# after building release file is not opening

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-build

I have created build for windows using flutter,
initially showing error #flutter_window.ddl,#printing_ddl, now after resolving this
build is created in installer folder(I have created new one) when I clicking on the name.exe file ,it isn't opening and nothing showing.
plugin i have used:

```yaml
  sqflite_common_ffi:
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid:
  data_table_2: ^2.5.9
  syncfusion_flutter_xlsio: 
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.1 

  sqflite:
  mobx: ^2.2.1
  sizer: ^2.0.15
  responsive_grid_list:
  flutter_tilt: ^2.2.0
  http:
  provider: ^6.1.1
  get: ^4.6.6
  flash:
  marquee: any
  intl:
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  pdf: any
  printing: any
```

maybe issues with plugin?
please helps guys.
thankyou

i have tried all thing by using chat gpt ,stack overflow please help
now i have crreted build by using this yt video link :
https://youtu.be/1J6P6L-vH9s?si=Tlig3y2Bc8V1bqlw

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution,
firstly use all ddl file
1.sqfLite3
2.vcruntime140.dll
3.vcruntime140_1.dll
4.msvcp140.dll

and main important thing is do not store setup file in program file(X86) store it in d drive or in other (if you are using sqflite(ffi))

Comment: Need formating and grammar fixes